# Xamarin Android Deployment Error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017

I have an app that works well on my Android 7.0 physical device and also works fine with the emulator that works on Android 6.0 API 23. I wanted to test my app if it works on Android 5.1 API 22 (Nexus 4). Well, it doesn't and it gives this error:

[image]

The Android Manifest looks like this:

[image]

The Android Options page looks like this:

[image]

The advanced options for the Android options page looks like this:

[image]

The Application options:  [image]

**Note: I have tried using the Supported Architecture menu in the advanced tab and have tried only selecting "x86_64" and it did not solve the error for me.

I got this from the output of Xamarin Diagnostics:

```
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 7.3.1.2
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community New\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community New\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_f80dbffe\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_f80dbffe\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_f80dbffe\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 22, 23, 24, 25
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 710f5e7a device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a getprop
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\cx67\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 5 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 5 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554    offline, 710f5e7a   device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 2 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554    device, 710f5e7a    device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 2 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 date +%s
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.extra" "debug=127.0.0.1:29274:29275,timeout=1499696237,loglevel=0,server=y"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.ExternalStorageDirectory"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 "echo" "-n" "${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "LoginSystem.Android/md50ef850b548eeb6d8287c9a52e2084363.SplashActivity"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 ps
[D:GetLogCat]:            logcat -v time
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 logcat -v time
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am force-stop LoginSystem.Android
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.connect" ""
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 5 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 710f5e7a device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 5 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 5 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554    offline, 710f5e7a   device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 2 devices
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554    device, 710f5e7a    device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 2 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a date +%s
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a setprop "debug.mono.extra" "debug=127.0.0.1:29276:29277,timeout=1499697764,loglevel=0,server=y"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.ExternalStorageDirectory"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "LoginSystem.Android/md50ef850b548eeb6d8287c9a52e2084363.SplashActivity"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a ps
[D:GetLogCat]:            logcat -v time
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a logcat -v time
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a am force-stop LoginSystem.Android
[D:RunShellCommand]:      710f5e7a setprop "debug.mono.connect" ""
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 22, 23, 24, 25
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_22,LoginSystem.Android" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 pm install "/data/local/tmp/LoginSystem.Android-Signed.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 rm "/data/local/tmp/LoginSystem.Android-Signed.apk"
[E:]:                     Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/LoginSystem.Android-Signed.apk
Failure [0]

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in C:\d\lanes\4699\fec6f88f\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\external\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 325
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass91_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in C:\d\lanes\4699\fec6f88f\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\external\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 740
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Running the app in release mode gives this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Void Android.App.Activity::OnRequestPermissionsResult(System.Int32,System.String[],Android.Content.PM.Permission[])' (defined in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.App.Activity::OnRequestPermissionsResult(System.Int32,System.String[],Android.Content.PM.Permission[])
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run(Pipeline pipeline, LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() LoginSystem.Android
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Target Android Version to 6.0 has solved this error.